# print data from MySQL using php7

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with the columns "email, senha, apelido and data_criacao". I made a login system using PHP and MySQL and now I want to display a message with the user nickname (which is Apelido) but I just can't. I tried all night long...

I've tried fetching, tried a while loop...

File: **login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('conexao.php');

if(empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['senha'])){
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['email']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']);
$query = "select apelido from cadastros where email = '{$email}' and 
senha=md5('{$senha}')";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

$row1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
if($row1 == 1){
$apelido = $row1['apelido'];
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $apelido;
header('Location: painel.php');
exit();
} else {
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}
?>
```

File: **painel.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('verifica_login.php');
?>

<h2><?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']; ?></h2>
<h2> <a href="logout.php">SAIR</h2>
```

It is supposed to show the "apelido" but nothing happens when I submit the form. It works perfect if I change `$_SESSION['usuario'] = $apelido;` to `$_SESSION['usuario'] = $email;` , it shows the email normally

Comment: You need to actually fetch the result set. E.g. with [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc).

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: How? i tried but i think i did it wrong

Comment: Oh no i'm not using md5 for real i'm just learning how to build an web application with databases, i'll get deeper into security stuff before building something for real

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually fetching the data returned by your query. `$result1` is just a pointer to the whole result set, it does not contain the actual row data. To get at the data you must fetch it (either [one row at a time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), or [all at once](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)). Most PHP/mysqli tutorials would show you this additional step. You've tried to use the result of `mysqli_num_rows()`, which is just a numeric value showing how many rows the query returned, as if it was an array containing actual row data.

In your case it seems you are only expecting one row, so you can do it like this:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

if ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) //if there is a row to read, this will both assign the row data into $row1 and also cause the if statement to return true
{
  $apelido = $row1['apelido'];
  //...etc
```